# XPath 1.0 select siblings with namespaces

Tags: c#, xpath

I have the following xml file

```
<root xmlns="http://mynamespace">
  <parent>
    <first>text</first>
    <second>more</second>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <first>2</first>
    <second>3</second>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <first>aa</first>
    <second>bb</second>
  </parent>
</root>
```

I'm trying to get `first` and `second` children of parent.

C# seems to have problems with the following code (the error is on the last line):

```
var rawXml = @"<root xmlns=""http://mynamespace"">
              <parent>
                <first>text</first>
                <second>more</second>
                <third>hello</third>
              </parent>
              <parent>
                <first>2</first>
                <second>3</second>
                <parent>
                  <first>a</first>
                  <second>b</second>
                </parent>
              </parent>
              <parent>
                <first>aa</first>
                <second>bb</second>
              </parent>
            </root>";

var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(rawXml);

var ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("m", "http://mynamespace");

var nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();

var parents = nav.Select("//m:parent", ns);

Console.Write($"Got {parents.Count} parents.");

// this does not work
// error: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
//var siblings = nav.Select("//m:parent/(m:first|m:second)", ns);

// but this does
var siblings = nav.Select("//m:parent/m:first|//m:parent/m:second", ns);
Console.Write($"Got {siblings.Count} children.");
```

Am I missing something? Is the first XPath expression wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the first XPath expression wrong?

Yes, it's not valid XPath 1.0 syntax. You can't have a `(` after a `/` in XPath 1.0.

You can achieve what you're trying to do, without repeating any node names, by using this path:

```xml
/m:root/m:parent/*[self::m:first or self::m:second]
```

Side note: avoid using `//` unless you have a specific reason to use it. It's bad for performance.

Comment: Can you please point me to where this is not allowed on the standard because I'll need to file a bug against our tool vendor and it does accept `(` after a `/` in XPath 1.0 mode.

Comment: @RedX https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#location-paths Production [3] in the spec defines RelativeLocationPaths as `Step`, `RelativeLocationPath '/' Step` or `AbbreviatedRelativeLocationPath`. From this, we can see that the part after the `/` has to match the production for `Step`, which is production [4]. Production [4] is defined as `AxisSpecifier NodeTest Predicate*` 
or `AbbreviatedStep`. Neither AxisSpecifier, nor NodeTest, nor Predicate, nor AbbreviatedStep can start with a `(` (feel free to verify that for yourself), so a `(` can not come at the beginning of a ...

Comment: @RedX step (i.e. after a slash). FYI, I believe that in XPath 2.0, parentheses after slashes _are_ allowed, but .NET's System.Xml uses XPath 1.0. If you need to use XPath 2.0+ paths, I would suggest looking into 3rd party XPath processors such as Saxon.